# Onchange, onclick events not working in Internet explorer 11

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, internet-explorer, struts

I was testing my existing code in different browsers and following code is working fine in IE 8,9, Firefox. But it does not seem to work in IE 11. What change will be required?

```
 <html:select multiple="true" property="sourceList" size="15" style="width:70px"
onchange="listSelectionChanged(this);" >
```

and

```
 function listSelectionChanged( list){
alert("list length = " + list.value.length );
alert("list is " + list.value);

// some code stuff here
}
```

The problem that i am facing is that in all the other browsers except IE 11, i am getting 
the alerts as expected with the correct length. In case of IE 11 , when i use keyboard keys to select the content i get the right result but when i use mouse click to select the content, i do not get any alerts. If i use onmousedown instead of onchange, i get alert but the length is 0 and value is null.

EDIT:

Client Side Code:

```
<select name="sourceList" multiple="multiple" size="15"
onchange="listSelectionChanged(this, 'addLine');" style="width:70px">
<option value="1:0:0">1:0:0</option>
<option value="1:0:1">1:0:1</option>
<option value="1:0:2">1:0:2</option>
<option value="1:0:3">1:0:3</option>
<option value="1:0:4">1:0:4</option></select>
```

Just mentioning, length will come as 5 in other browsers.

Comment: It sure would be nice to see the actual HTML and not the serverside code

Comment: Do "all the other browsers" include IE10?

Comment: @Quentin i just checked on IE10. The behavior is same as IE11. Things not working as expected.

Comment: What does the JavaScript error console say?

Comment: @Quentin how can i check the JavaScript console?

Comment: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers

Comment: @Quentin  I get the following error: SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'parentNode' of undefined or null reference

Comment: NOTE: updated the question with client side code.

Comment: Your code is missing any mention of `parentNode`, so the problem (or, at least, **a** problem) exists somewhere in code you haven't shared yet.

Comment: But my point is this issue is coming only in IE 10 and 11. I guess the list is not populating.

Comment: @Quentin I guess , i found a way.  Including     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" /> will solve the problem (i tested a page using above tag in plain html). But my problem here is i am using struts html tags in my application. Any idea, how to put compatiblity tag in struts html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though i could not fix the absurd behavior of onBlur event on Safari, but i found a simple workaround that might help someone who is also facing the same issue. In addition to firing the alert of wrong input, i also changed the value to 0(default) in case invalid field is entered. This way the focus is reset and infinite loop is avoided.